# Parsing protocol and url from packet payload

Tags: networking, c, ethernet

We are using pf_ring to capture packets. We are able to decipher information like source and destination ip, mac etc from the header information. Now we are moving into payload to decide the type of protocol, url and other information. We see that tcpdump and wireshark have done good parsing. Are those source code just for parsing is available given that we can provide each byte by byte into the function?

Comment: The source for `tcpdump` and `wireshark` is available -- why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: yes i dont want to reinvent the wheel. The problem I have been going through the tcpdump source I dont get it which part is doing this? Any idea or indication which function is performing all this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at things like `bro-ids`, `snort`, `surricata`, `httpry`. [bro-ids](http://www.bro.org/) is probably the closest to what you're looking for.

Comment: I have download bro-ids but I cant find the place where they do this sort of parsing any idea please?

Comment: they wrote their own language to do it. It's all in the `.bro` files. They've got some good documentation on how it works.

Comment: I am looking something in C is that availalbe ?

Comment: @biz14, Why not using the wireshark code then? What are you trying to do in the end?

Comment: use `libpcap library`.

Comment: @Where to get the wiresharks codes. What I am trying to do is just parse the capture payload to identify its protocol and its url if exist? So what is best solution you recommend here?

Comment: @Mohsen so which one is better to be followed libpcap or tcpdump?

Comment: `tcpdump` itself uses `libpcap`.

Comment: So which go to with now ? I am now running tcpdump and trying to grab how there are parsing those packets. Any other simple examples?